# Getting Database Connection Error. MariaDB shutdown frequently. What to do?

Tags: database, mariadb, connection

> ```
> 200813 09:19:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
> 200813 18:06:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
> 200813 18:06:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.65-MariaDB) starting as process 12673 ...
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 200813 18:06:28 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
> InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
> InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
> InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
> 200813 18:06:28  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
> 200813 18:06:29 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 1437392
> 136
> 200813 18:06:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 200813 18:06:29 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
> 200813 18:06:29 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
> 200813 18:06:29 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
> Version: '5.5.65-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
> 200813 18:10:01 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './sentora_core/x_bandwidth' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
> 200813 18:10:01 [Warning] Checking table:   './sentora_core/x_bandwidth'
> 200813 18:10:01 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './sentora_core/x_mysql_databases' is marked as crashed and should be
> ```
>
> repai
> red
> 200813 18:10:01 [Warning] Checking table:   './sentora_core/x_mysql_databases'
> 200814 21:14:02 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
> 200814 21:14:02 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
> 200814 21:14:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.65-MariaDB) starting as process 23766 ...
> 200814 21:14:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
> 200814 21:14:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
> 200814 21:14:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7

Comment: Near the end of the output there are a couple of tables `marked as crashed and should be repaired`, might fix the issue. Google how to repair tables based on the storage engine in use.

Comment: Thanx Bro, let me try this.